# Eclipse CDT Debug not in executable format: File format not recognized after strawberry installation

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw, eclipse-cdt, strawberry-perl

Maybe I'm missing something obvious since I searched the internet for quite a while but could not find a solution for the following problem:

I'm using Eclipse Kepler SP2 (Build id: 20140224-0627) with CDT and MinGW as compiler backend. Debugging C code with gdb worked great up until today (at least I noticed the problem today). 
Now I get the following error message when i want to start a progam in the debugger:

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-file-exec-and-symbols C:/[...]/Debug/test.exe
Error message from debugger back end:
"C:\[...]\Debug\test.exe": not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

The program runs nicely and so I thought I might have screwed up some settings. But when I tried to debug an old program, everything worked until I recomplied the old program -> same problem. If I ask the C-wizard to create a new "Hello World" ANSI C application with MinGW, the same problem occurs.

The compile commands which were used are

```
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\test.o" "..\\src\\test.c" 
gcc -o test.exe "src\\test.o"
```

I did not update my MinGW in between, but updated Eclipse.

Do you have any pointers on where to look for the problem?

**Edit**: I just checked the binary type: My old projects are all [x86/le], the newly compiled ones are [amd64/le]. This should be a trace.... Will update posting according to progress.

**Edit2**: *argh* I installed strawberry perl a few days ago, and the installer has changed the environment variable `MINGW_HOME` in origin BUILD SYSTEM to `c:\strawberry\c` and this screwed up my builds. Resetting it to my `c:\MinGW` solved the issue. 
I'll post this as answer, too. Heading and tags have been updated to point to this issue more directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I installed strawberry perl a few days ago, and the installer has changed the environment variable `MINGW_HOME` in origin BUILD SYSTEM to `c:\strawberry\c` and this screwed up my builds. Resetting it to my `c:\MinGW` solved the issue.

BTW: This happened, because strawberry added `c:\strawberry\c` to the PATH in front of my custom `c:\MinGW` and eclipse adds those to the BUILD SYSTEM variables.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a parser problem, what is your binary parser under Project/Properties/Build/Settings ?

Comment: It's "PE Winwods Parser", I tried some of the others, but the problem persists.

Comment: strawberry-perl messed up my configurations - thanks for your answer, at least it was a starting point for solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check Project->Properties ->C/C++ Build ->environment and path for MINGW_HOME 
make sure you have right gdb version (by checking under debug Configuration ->environment).